# Some apps change the sound profile when showing notifications

Tags: notifications, audio, 6.0-marshmallow, htc-desire-816-dual

Some apps such as WhatsApp and Gmail cause my sound profile to change from Vibrate to Normal automatically without asking me when I get a notification from them. This only happens when notification sounds are enabled in the app, but they really should be respecting the system settings instead of changing them! Also, they should not be enabling my ringer!

I want notification sounds to work if I changed the sound profile to Normal, and only vibration in the Vibrate profile.

Of those two apps, only WhatsApp has permission to change audio settings.

HTC Desire 816 dual sim, Android 6